# Why does it remove the content of the file?

Tags: php

I've been getting irritated by this bug, and I've tried to fix it but it's been a struggle for me. So I have a php file write to a .txt file, but as I enter different info, it replaces the info that was already in the file, but I don't want it to do that. I want it to add on. Help?

```
<?php
$filenum = echo rand();
$info = $_GET["info"]; //You have to get the form data
$file = fopen('$filenum.txt', 'w+'); //Open your .txt file
$content = $info. PHP_EOL .$gain. PHP_EOL .$offset;
fwrite($file , $content); //Now lets write it in there
fclose($file ); //Finally close our .txt
die(header("Location: ".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]));
```

?>

Comment: I see somebody downvoted. Was that supposed to even help me at all? What was your purpose?

Comment: They never say why. Maybe it's because they think a trivial amount of research on your part would have solved the problem. All you have to do is read the documentation of the `fopen()` function to see it.

Comment: well almost every line of this is wrong  -- so you really want to be start with the basics (not my downvote)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `w+` mode, and the documentation clearly says:

> Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and **truncate the file to zero length**. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

If you want to append, you should use `a` or `a+`.

BTW, I'm not nor sure why you're using `w+` rather than just `w`, since you're never reading the file.

Also, you can do it all in one statement using `file_put_contents()`

```
$filenum = rand();
$info = $_GET['info'];
$content = $info . PHP_EOL . $gain . PHP_EOL . $offset . PHP_EOL;
file_put_contents("$filenum.txt", $content, FILE_APPEND);
die(header("Location: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']));
```

And notice that you should have `PHP_EOL` at the end of `$content`. Otherwise, every time you add to the file, it will start on the same line as the last line you added previously.

Comment: is `die(header("Location: ".$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]));` valid ?

Comment: @nogad It's strange, but I think it will work. It's equivalent to `header(...); die('');`

Comment: needs a dot or you get Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_SERVER' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: `die(header("Location: ". $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']));` of course local testing puts me in to a death loop, so could be dangerous if user hits reload

Comment: @nogad This is presumably the target of a form submission. That header redirects you back to the page with the form.

Comment: @nogad Obviously, anyone who uses this method of redirecting back to the previous page wouldn't do that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the solution but I would recommend you to see the file format you are opening in, I think it should be 'a+' or something like that which opens file for appending rather than 'w+'. I haven't used php much but I think that's the case

Comment: Yep, I got it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @WavyFX You should accept the answer if it helped you.